# How can I get more information about a fault in system.net.http?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` from `System.Net.Http` on nuget to make a request from a module (assembly) written in c#. This needs to work with a legacy application in Windows XP so we're using .Net Framework 4.0.

I can successfully send a https request to our server from my Windows 10 machine; however, when I test it from Windows XP in a VM, I get a fault. I can request websites like `https://google.com` but our `https` site causes a fault. On top of all this, the `res.StackTrace` is `null`! The Message I get from `obj.Exception.InnerException` is `An error ocurred while sending the request`. I can however get to our site in a browser in the VM without trouble. So why can't I get a StackTrace? Could this be some kind of ssl trust issue (our site has an ssl certificate from godaddy)?

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SERVER_BASE_URL); // https://...
// Works when BaseAddress="https://google.com" but not our https site
return client.GetAsync("/").ContinueWith(res =>
{
    if (res.IsFaulted)
        // res.StackTrace is empty >:( 
        MessageBox.Show("Faulted");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
});
```

Comment: `res.Exception` is `AggregateException`, so try see [InnerExceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.innerexceptions(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: There is only one which is the InnerException that I refered to in the post

Comment: are you try get `StackTrace` from InnerException?

Comment: Ahah, I see. I needed ```res.Exception.InnerException.GetBaseException()``` which has a stack trace on it. Somehow I missed the nested ```InnerException```s. So the real issue is ```The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procdure```. Seems to be an ssl certificate issue. Anyway around that? Also I'll update the original post

Comment: I think I have enough info to get further on this. The question is no longer relevant now that I know more about the issue from the base exception. Thanks @Grundy